# Symfony2, Doctrine2, Entity Repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

We have such repository

```
class CronInfoCharacterInfoRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param string|integer $characterID
     * @return void
     */
    public function add($characterID)
    {
        if (!$this->find($characterID)) {

            $oEntry = new CronInfoCharacterInfo();
            $oEntry->setCharacterID($characterID);

            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($oEntry);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

But I want insert new entry by DQL. How can I do this  through $this->createQueryBuilder()... ? And is it normal to use 'entity manager' inside repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant insert using DQL the very documentation says about that

> INSERT statements are not allowed in DQL, because entities and their
>   relations have to be introduced into the persistence context through
>   EntityManager#persist() to ensure consistency of your object model.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

And it is perfectly ok to use enitity manager inside Repo. What you are doing now is correct !